# ipython notebook pandas plot is different from interactive shell

Tags: python, pandas, plot, jupyter-notebook

I tried to plot a pandas dataframe with **multiple series** in **ipython notebook**. I used the pandas plot feature to do it and the result is different from what i tested in python interactive shell. Ipython notebook only plots one of the four series in the dataframe.

Below is the code:

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,4).cumsum(0),columns=['A','B','C','D'],index=np.arange(0,100,10))
df.plot(ax=ax)
```

Comment: Did you run the code in ipython notebook? Any chance that you can post your result snapshot here?

Comment: Yep, works in ipython notebook, all 4 series.

Comment: Are your shell and notebook using the same versions of python and matplotlib?

Comment: I got the same result after restart ipython notebook. Should i delete the question?